# What happens when these 3 chemicals are mixed in air?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, safety

What happens when these 3 chemicals are mixed in air?

1. Pentanone/Di-isopropyl Ketone (2,4-Dimethyl-3-Pentanone)
2. Iodine, reagent grade
3. Sodium Iodide, reagent grade.

The 3 parts make up a liquid in a tilt switch.  The tilt switch can leak giving off a very unpleasant smell.  Also corrosion can occur on the part.  What is the smell?  How dangerous is the smell?  Using a fume cupboard etc, what exactly are we emitting into the atmosphere?

Comment: There's a chance you're getting [iodination of the ketones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketone_halogenation). The resulting α-iodoketones could be acrid/lachrymatory.